# socket io client return disconnected

Tags: websocket, socket.io

i want to make an automated chat in the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.anonchat
and ran into websocket
[fiddler screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlob.png)

i try it and another combinations, but cant connect

```
const socket = io.connect('https://anonchatapi.stivisto.com',
{query: {
 version:'3.9.1',
 language:'ru',
 platform:'android',
 deviceInfo:'samsung SM-G977N',
 systemInfo:'Android 5.1.1',
 cookie:'3bfa4edc-3c99-48d5-ba9c-2305b7771994',
 secret:'U2FsdGVkX1+RTHTFXotg1jNhp9UdCyGoq4GNYmjRiNXgamGNXrjaXuoa23PJtIHRnlP+xRtXut6Rdbz1bCkm+N/MAYSIB2FDTdkYxReFDzE=',
},
transports: ['websocket'],
extraHeaders: {
 'Cookie': '__cfduid=d8c5c875e657a6996f040fdbefb81525a1609957302; __cflb=0H28vwUUvyk1WC5Cn8KUkUHh5BL9vWCsQL4m3TepR29; io=1pOXWig4qOhPEbceAJDA',
'origin': 'https://anonchatapi.stivisto.com',
'Upgrade': 'websocket',
'Connection': 'Upgrade',
'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'K1OkajjYjq9nJS7oHoQUwg==',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version': 13,
'Host': 'anonchatapi.stivisto.com',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.12.1'
}

});
console.log(socket.open())

socket.on('connect', () => {
 console.log('EEEE!')
});
```

request in fiddler

```
Cookie: __cfduid=d8c5c875e657a6996f040fdbefb81525a1609957302; __cflb=0H28vwUUvyk1WC5Cn8KUkUHh5BL9vWCsQL4m3TepR29; io=1pOXWig4qOhPEbceAJDA
origin: https://anonchatapi.stivisto.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: K1OkajjYjq9nJS7oHoQUwg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Host: anonchatapi.stivisto.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.12.1
```

[websocket screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZICq.png)

```
431[null,{"user":{"uid":"b4957eb5-2145-46b5-ae79-94b10f7a9f26","exploreDialogId":"5ff6354c84624f424b8ea28b","createdAt":"2021-01-06T18:21:43.107Z","lastUpdatedAt":"2021-01-06T22:17:55.002Z","language":"ru","ban":null,"hasPremium":false,"searchPreferences":{"male":false,"female":false},"settings":{"public":{"gender":"female","username":"","aboutMe":"","showPremiumStatus":false,"profilePicture":null},"pushNotifications":{"newMessage":{"sounds":true,"show":true},"dialog":{"sounds":true,"show":true},"like":{"sounds":true,"show":true}}},"token":"fIDquK0QlSo:APA91bHV6z_s58aWewbVxS9fugMbaPNp0krEO1h9_z7R48csM5Q9Z0Eq80IpF_aQUzqOiE_60l0Nj4NkOWSTEEh6mHMH2mtaTAG2-Erm8Tw3UrLXlzyf5lwlD5Qru-0RFM__9Z93cYtr"}}]
```

how me need make it work?

Answer (score 0):

socket.io lib dont suport latest node version.
v14.15.4 work good

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const debug = require('debug');
debug.enable('socket.io-client');

const socket = io.connect('https://anonchatapi.stivisto.com',
  {
    query: {
      version: '3.9.1',
      language: 'ru',
      platform: 'android',
      deviceInfo: 'samsung SM-G977N',
      systemInfo: 'Android 5.1.1',
      cookie: '3bfa4edc-3c99-48d5-ba9c-2305b7771994',
      secret: 'U2FsdGVkX1+RTHTFXotg1jNhp9UdCyGoq4GNYmjRiNXgamGNXrjaXuoa23PJtIHRnlP+xRtXut6Rdbz1bCkm+N/MAYSIB2FDTdkYxReFDzE=',
    },
    transports: ['websocket']
  });

socket.connect();

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('EEEE!')
});
```